# Are you able to help me understand this Java code?

Tags: java, arrays, foreach

I am confused about a few things here. The ++alpha/--alpha and the inside of the array [c - 'a']. I ran it through debug and I noticed a 1 gets stored. But I don't understand why this is the case and what the - 'a' is doing.

```
boolean test = true;
String r = "aa";
String m = "baab";
int[] alpha = new int[26];
        
for(char c: m.toCharArray())
   ++alpha[c - 'a'];
        
for(char c: r.toCharArray()){
   if(alpha[c - 'a'] != 0)
        --alpha[c - 'a'];
   else
        test = false;
}
System.out.print(test);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code counts the number of characters by making full use of the fact that a `char` can be cast to an integer and used in an array `int[] alpha = new int[26];` that is 26 characters long to correspond to the letters of the alphabet, and requires minimal code to do so.

In short, the following code simply adds `++` or `+1` to the array whenever the corresponding character is found in the `m` string:

```
for(char c: m.toCharArray())
   ++alpha[c - 'a'];
```

And the second loop simply subtracts `--` or `-1` from the array whenever the corresponding character is found in the `r` string:

```
for(char c: r.toCharArray())
   if(alpha[c - 'a'] != 0)
        --alpha[c - 'a'];
```

---

In more detail:

The `++` and `--` simply increment or decrement the associated variable, and putting it before the variable `++alpha[x]` just means it will perform the operation and then assign the incremented value rather than the other way around if it was after `alpha[x]++`, however, that makes no difference in this code example though:

For example for the following code:

```
alpha[0] = 0;
++alpha[0]; //or alpha[0]++;
System.out.println("The value was: " + alpha[0]);
```

We get this result:

```
The value was: 1
```

As for `[c - 'a']`, the value of a `char` for example `'a'` is actually 97 which we can see by doing `System.out.println((int)'a');`, and this is helpful because it means we can use a char variable directly instead of an integer to write less code in some cases. So it is really just `[c - 97]`, however, if we look at it in context we can see that `c` is also a character from the `m` string, so for the first char we get:

```
String m = "baab";
for(char c: m.toCharArray()){
    ++alpha[c - 'a'];
```

The `c` is equal to 'b' in the first iteration of the loop like so:

```
    ++alpha['b' - 'a'];
```

But we know that a char behaves like an integer where `a`=97 and `b`=98 like so:

```
    ++alpha[98 - 97];
```

And for the first char 'b' in the loop it actually ends up resulting in:

```
++alpha[1];//98-97=1
```

And if we now expand the ++ it look like this:

```
alpha[1] = alpha[1] + 1;
```

If the character was a z for example it would work the same way where `['z'-'a']` is the same as `[122-97]` which equates to [25]:

```
alpha['z'-'a'] = alpha['z'-'a'] + 1;

//which is the same as
alpha[122-97] = alpha[122-97] + 1;

//which equates to
alpha[25] = alpha[25] + 1;
```